# Style text in button or button itself so it does not take up extra vertical space

Tags: html, css

[image: color buttons]

I have added a bullet character inside a button that I'd like larger, but horizontally and vertically centered without it raising up the button higher. I've tried styling the button so that there is 0px line-height and margin, but it has no effect.

The style of the button is as follows:

```
font-size: 21px;
/* margin: 0px; */
/* line-height: 0px; */
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background-color: rgb(128, 32, 255);
```

It also has a class with some extra css:

```
.paletteButton {
    border: 1px outset black;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}
```

The html for this button is:

```
<button class="paletteButton" style="font-size: 21px;/* margin: 0px; *//* line-height: 0px; */width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: rgb(128, 32, 255);">•</button>
```

Comment: add `vertical-align: top` to your button

Comment: Thanks that works for keeping the button in the same place, and vertically centered if I made line height 0px. I've tried making text-align:center, but it does not align it horizontally.